# combobox con datos de varios campos en filas ms access

Tags: ms-access

He creado una tabla con varias columnas y un formulario asociado. En este formulario he insertado un comobobox para que me aparezcan los valores de las columnas de la tabla en distintas filas del desplegable.

En mi tabla tengo 3 columnas con 3 campos distintos en los que aparecen los nombres de 3 productos para un pedido: producto1, producto2 y producto3. Cuando hago el combobox me aparecen los valores de los productos separados en 3 columnas diferenciadas dentro de la misma fila. Pero lo que necesito es que aparezcan los valores de referencia1, referencia2 y referencia3 uno debajo de otro en el desplegable del comobobox para poder selecionarlos.

He leído en los foros que podría hacerse con una consulta de unión y seleccionando la consulta como origen de fila en el combobox, pero obtengo el mismo resultado y no sé qué estoy haciendo mal.

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Si los 3 campos están en la misma fila, efectivamente tendrás que hacerte una consulta UNION, Mira en w3schools sobre las consultas UNION ALL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yo he hecho algo rápido. Una tabla con 3 campos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego me he hecho una consulta UNION ALL:

```
SELECT TBL1.Primer_Campo
FROM TBL1
UNION ALL
SELECT TBL1.Segundo_Campo
FROM TBL1
UNION ALL
SELECT TBL1.Tercer_Campo
FROM TBL1;
```

Y el resultado que obtengo es esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**ACTUALIZACIÓN:** He añadido un campo autonumérico a la tabla, para identificar a cada registro de manera única.

Ahora mi tabla es así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y mi código SQL es:

```
SELECT TBL1.Tercer_Campo, TBL1.ID
FROM TBL1
UNION ALL
SELECT TBL1.Segundo_Campo, TBL1.ID
FROM TBL1
UNION ALL
SELECT TBL1.Primer_Campo, TBL1.ID
FROM TBL1
ORDER BY TBL1.ID;
```

Y el resultado es así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

De todas maneras, si tienes que deformar tantísimo tu tabla, me da a mí que no lo estás diseñando bien, porque no es muy habitual esta consulta que estás haciendo, pero bueno, te puede servir.

Si tienes muchos registros, al ser una consulta tan compleja, es posible que te sobrecargue, tenlo en cuenta.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Elier, es casi lo que necesito. Lo único que faltaría es que la consulta devolviera los datos separados en columnas diferenciando cada registro de la tabla, transponiendo la tabla. Es decir, que en la primera columna devolviera:1A;1B;1C. En la segunda columna, 2A; 2B; 2C. Y en la tercera columna, 3A; 3B; 3C. ¿Sería posible hacerlo así?

Comment: @Ruy Mira la respuesta actualizada.

Comment: @¿Te sirvió? Si la respuesta ayudó, márcala como correcta. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, Elier, sí, me fue muy útil.